# Frontend category only showing last 3 grouped products

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1.7

So i have a problem with 1 category in my shop that is displaying only the last 3 items. The reason why is unknown.

**Explanation**

I have a total of 20 grouped products in this category and a total of 100 products under those 20 grouped products (5/grouped product). Now when i go to `

> products->categories->the category-> products in category

i can choose which products are displayed within that category. If i select 4 items only the last 3 will display (last 3 in that list according to ID).

***So :***

- Product 1 -> not show
- Product 2 -> shown
- Product 3 -> shown
- Product 4    -> shown

***If i add another product then :***

- Product 1 -> not show
- Product 2 -> not show
- Product 3 -> shown
- Product 4    -> shown
- Product 5    -> shown

And so on.

**Even more so** if i put the indexing to 'on save' it has not issues but that not ideal for sending emails as far as i understand. I would need to resave every product in order to show them. But as soon as the `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` runs (trough cron or manual) it would go back to only showing the last 3 items.

**Even more weird** is that this is only withing 1 category as far as i can see (a lot of category's so i can't be 100% sure).

I have this problems since updating to *magento 2.1.7*

anyone any idea?

**Note**

If i add another simple product it shows 3 products (2 grouped and that single product). So i this is for all products and not only grouped

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue for this 1 category by deleting it and recreating it.

No idea what the problem is/was.

I will now do a check if every category has all the products within them. or the problem has been moved. Also i will verify this as an answer if the problem did not move to another category

**Note :** problem was indexer being invalid and caching being invalid because of a module called 'Plumrocket Private sales'. After deleting it i could run indexer and caching again and all problems where solved!